# Button adding classes to HTML element using .classList.add(), reverts itself on first click

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a simple button which when clicked will add or remove some classes from a HTML element based on a boolean cookie value.
The button and class updating behaves almost exactly as it should, however on the first click it does not. On the first click (when debugging) I can see that the classes are applied correctly and the interface updates, but then the element reverts to its previous state after the function has been completed.
Any suggestions on what might be causing this are welcome.

```html
<button type="button" id="nav_expand"></button>
```

```js
document.getElementById("nav_expand").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  setExpand(false);
});

function setExpand(init) {
  debugger;
  if (getCookie('navbar_expand') === true) {
    toggleCookie('navbar_expand');
    document.body.classList.remove('classOne');
    document.body.classList.remove('classTwo');
  } else {
    toggleCookie('navbar_expand');
    document.body.classList.add('classOne');
    document.body.classList.add('classTwo');
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to figure out the initial value of `getCookie('navbar_expand')` then work your logic from there. I have a feeling it's not what you are expecting, such as it being `null`.

Comment: Do you have problem only on first click and from second click it works properly?

Comment: That is something which I considered computercarguy, In my actual code the initial value is handled, I left that out to simplify the example. Yes I only have the problem on the initial click.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that there was a custom class (that I was unaware existed) which was toggling the same class values which I was trying to manually alter. Resulting in the strange behaviour.